# Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I writed this trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_abort_insert]
ON [dbo].[F_DOCCURRENTPIECE]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN

IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM Inserted i  
           INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.CBMARQ= d.CBMARQ
           WHERE i.DC_Piece <> d.DC_Piece 
             AND i.DC_Domaine = 0

            AND i.DC_IdCol = 6)
COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH  
SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
        ROLLBACK
END CATCH;
END
```

I'am having this error: 
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 2

Pleaze help me

Comment: The problem is because you have a trigger with a transaction in it. This causes untold amounts of grief. I am 99.9999% certain your calling code is in a transaction right? Remove the transaction from your trigger.

Comment: okay when I remove the begin transaction and commit transaction then trigger is like don't recognize catch. Begin trans and commit are essential because the code won't execute with only try catch , also  when I remove the ty catch i had this error :  The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Comment: The existence of a transaction does not effect the flow of statements or prevent a try/catch from working. What are you really trying to do here? A transaction in a trigger is not going to work because there is already an implicit trigger in any dml statement. If you can explain your requirements we can help you fix this.

Comment: I had this table F_DOCCURRENTPIECE in it I had  this field DC_Piece by doing this trigger Iam previnting the system to jump a  DC_Piece value when another trigger is executed  (that i created) in another table

Comment: That is not helping explain what you are trying to do. perhaps you should look here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have nested transaction. I mean a transaction was open when trigger was fired. You need to modify your trigger to handle nested transaction like mentioned below :

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_abort_insert]
ON [dbo].[F_DOCCURRENTPIECE]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET XACT_ABORT ON
declare @trancount int = @@trancount

BEGIN TRY
    if @trancount > 0
        begin
            save transaction t1
        end
    else
        begin
            begin transaction
        end

IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM Inserted i  
           INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.CBMARQ= d.CBMARQ
           WHERE i.DC_Piece <> d.DC_Piece 
             AND i.DC_Domaine = 0

            AND i.DC_IdCol = 6)

    if @trancount = 0
        begin           
            COMMIT TRAN
        end
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 

    if @trancount > 0
        rollback transaction t1
    if @trancount = 0
        rollback transaction
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()

END CATCH;
```

end

This should work for you. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thank you so much i just tryed and it works very well, Iam very grateful